# Difference between using send method and dot method

Tags: ruby

The book *The Well Grounded Rubyist* states that you could use the `send` method as such to check if an object (`ticket`) responds to user input:

```
if ticket.respond_to?(request) 
  puts ticket.send(request)
else
  puts "No such information available"
end
```

What is the difference between the code above and writing:

```
if ticket.respond_to?(request) 
  puts ticket.request
else
  puts "No such information available"
end
```

If `ticket` responds to the user input, why not just call it directly using the dot notation?

Comment: `send` is not checking if an object responds; `respond_to?` is.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`ticket.request` sends the message `request` to the `ticket` object.

`ticket.send(request)` sends **whatever is contained in the variable `request`** to the `ticket` object. So if you had written `request = :clone` before this, that line would be equivalent to `ticket.clone`.

Comment: Also, if `:request` is a private method, it can be invoked with `ticket.send(:request)`, whereas `ticket.request` raises an exception.

Comment: After a little irb session I believe I understand.  In trying to put it in a simple notion, would you say that ticket.send(request) is more "literal?"  I'm trying to figure out how you describe the difference.

Comment: dscher, what is a method?  Is it not a message sent to a receiver?  `send` is the postie.

Comment: @dscher: OK, so the `.` operator sends the message on the right side to the object on the left. If you write `person.name`, it sends the message `name` to `person`. Whatever is on the right side of the dot, that's the message. With `send`, it also sends a message, but the message is whatever you pass in. So you can pass in a variable containing a message that isn't determined until runtime and it will send whatever message the variable specifies. (I wouldn't call it "more literal," but I guess you can if it helps. If I had to make a comparison like that, I guess I'd say "more dynamic.")

Comment: Does that mean that send's primary purpose is for dealing with messages that are generated at runtime?  I can write "something".reverse myself but if someone passes in :reverse(via the variable request) the only way to call that during runtime is "something".send(request)?  If that's correct then I really understand it now.

Comment: @dscher: That's right. `send` lets you send a message that isn't selected until runtime. Well, that and what Cary mentioned about getting around privacy constraints. (Ruby has a really odd definition of `private`. `private` basically means the method can't be called with the dot operator. Because of this, you can call private methods of other objects with `send`.)

Comment: Excellent.  Thanks a lot for your patience in explaining.